# BufferedReader with new InputStreamReader(System.in) throws an exception Temporarily unavailable resource

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader, system.in

In my standalone application I have to read the user input from console in different classes.
I created a static class member variable in Installer class

```
public static final BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

but Installer.buffReader.readLine(); throws an IO exception - **"Temporarily unavailable resource"** sometime

```
public static void startApplication() {
        System.out.println("Would you like to start the application? [y/n]");
        String userChoice = null;
        try {
            userChoice = Installer.buffReader.readLine();
            if (userChoice != null && userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                start();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception occured in startApplication() :{}", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

How can I debug or prevent it?

Comment: The problem isn't at `new InputStreamReader(...)`, it is at `readLine()`.

Answer (score -1):

I think is because you are calling here to the same method:

```
if (userChoice != null && userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            startApplication();
        }
```

so the second time you call the method is throwing you the exception because the bufferedReader is still opened.

Try to close the bufferedReader before with buffReader.close(). Or don't use the static for BufferedReader because if other part of the app is using it, you will have a exception as well.

EDIT:

I was searching a little bit in google and can be because your operative system that is blocking the input for any reason. I tried your code and for me is not failing. Check here is a similar case: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54859244/getting-error-on-input-java-io-ioexception-resource-temporarily-unavailable)

Comment: I corrected the code it is not called recursively!.

Comment: closing a buffReader with InputStreamReader(System.in) caused a lot of trouble so I made it static and closing it at the end of execution.

Comment: If he closes the `BufferedReader` he also closes `System.in`, which cannot be reopened. Not a good idea.

Comment: Try with the class Scanner if give you the same problem